# Need handrail for drop off of 600mm?

Tags: safety

Need handrail for level difference (600 mm) in a walkway area? this question has to do with safety, please also tell me what is the maximum acceptable step without hand rail.

I live in Qatar

Comment: Code varies from place to place. Telling us where you are will get you a general answer, but the specifics are up to your local authority having jurisdiction (AHJ). Suggest you call them.

Answer (score 2):

There are building code requirements for a porch: In the USA, if your porch floor is less than 30 inches high from the ground, a porch railing is NOT required by code. In Canada the maximum height from the ground is 24 inches.Sep 20, 2014.

Other parts of the world may have different codes or none at all.  So your question will have different answers depending on your location.

Since you live in Qatar I would use international building code which states the following

> On a stair, since handrail must be between 34" and 38", the handrail and the top of the guard can be one and the same. In commercial applications, the IBC requires a minimum height of 42". **On stairs, once there is a 30" drop, a handrail will be required and placed between 34" and 38" above the nosing.**

Short answer is that unless Qatar has codes that vary from international standard you don’t need a handrail for 600mm (23.62”)

Comment: in the state of QATAR.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging the difference in codes from country to country. BTW, a “handrail” to me is the item that extends along side a stair and a “guard” or “guardrail” is the item that keeps you from falling off a level to a lower level. I think you have the terms switched in your answer. A guard is required when there is a 30” or more drop and a handrail is required when there are 3 or more risers...regardless of the drop distance.